# reset field to default value without form

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, input

I have wrote jQuery method to change three buttons on click.

Edit, Save and Cancel.

When click on edit I display to default values of input fields.
If I change them and click cancel, Edit button is displayed again. If I again click on edit,
the input fields are not reset to default values, there are as I left them when clicked on Cancel button.

How can I on Cancel again return their default values?

```
<td class="text-center">
    <span class="key"> Hi </span>
    <input type="text" id="keyEdit" class="keyEdit text-center" value="Hello!" style="display: none">
</td>
<td class="text-center">
   <span class="value"> Hi Again </span>
   <input type="text" id="valueEdit" class="valueEdit text-center" value="World!" style="display: none">
 </td>
```

and buttons:

```
 <a id="edit" class="btn btn-warning edit"></a>
 <a id="save" class="btn btn-success save" style="display: none"></a>
 <a id="cancel" class="btn btn-danger cancel" style="display: none"></a>
```

And in my js file:

```
$("#my-table").on("click",".edit",function(e) {
   $(this).hide();
   $('.save, .cancel').show();

   $(".key, .value").hide();
   $(".keyEdit, .valueEdit").show();
});

$("#my-table").on("click",".cancel", function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $('.edit').show();
   $('.save, .cancel').hide();

   $(".keyEdit, .valueEdit").hide();
   $(".key, .value").show();
});
```

Comment: Put them in a form, then you can use the reset method of that. If you don’t want to do that, then you need to read the `defaultValue` property of the individual fields, and assign it as the current value. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement

Comment: These are input fields defined in table, so it will me tricky to do it in a form. @CBroe

Comment: What’s so tricky about surrounding an existing table with `<form>` and `</form>`, I wonder.

Comment: Because I have foreach in twig, so I think it won't work. Am I wrong? @CBroe

Comment: _“Am I wrong?”_ - in assuming the sentence before that, would be enough to answer that question? Well yes of course you are :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you can't add a wrapping `<form>` element, you could add something like this to your edit button `click` handler:

```js
$('input').each((i,e) => {
  e.value = e.defaultValue;
});
```

See [HTMLInputElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement).